# Why am I being asked for a return type when creating a constructor?

Tags: java, constructor

I'm trying to make a class and create two constructors in it. I've created it as I have done all of my previous classes and constructors, but for some reason it keeps telling me to add a return type to the two constructors.

I've tried to see if I've created this any different from my previous constructors but can't see any difference.

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong here?

```
public class Book {

    //instance variables
    //accessSpec type varname;
    private String title;
    private String author;
    private double price;

    //constructors
    public initialiseInstanceFields() {
        title = "";
        author = "";
        price = 0.00;
    }

    public initialiseInstanceFields(String titleIn, String authorIn, double priceIn) {
        title = titleIn;
        author = authorIn;
        price = priceIn;
    }


    //methods
    //accessSpec returntype varname(argList){}
    //return the title
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

}//end class
```

Comment: You don't just give whatever name you like to the constructor. It has to be same as the classname.

Comment: I don't see any constructor. Because constructor should have same name as class. Rename your class to "initialiseInstanceFields"

Comment: @Rupesh It's better to rename the constructor to `Book` isn't it?

Comment: sure thing... whatever he like... :D

Comment: Downvotes seem harsh.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Constructors must have the same name as the class name. `initialiseInstanceFields` is a normal method and not a constructor and hence a return type is required. If you want it to be treated as a constructor then redefine it using the name of class i.e `Book` Change your constructors definition as:

```
public Book()
{
    title = "";
    author = "";
    price = 0.00;
}

public Book(String titleIn, String authorIn, double priceIn)
{
    title = titleIn;
    author = authorIn;
    price = priceIn;
}
```

Comment: "Should" should be "must".